# ExtJs rownumberer issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using **ExtJs Gird** for displaying data from my DB. I am using `{ text: 'No.', xtype: 'rownumberer' }` to number the rows. Everything is fine except that the **rownumberer** is not working as expected in **google chrome**. If I have 140 records, the **rownumberer** is working fine till the **99th record** and after that for all the rows it displays some dots like (**...**). Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the column gets to to small, when the row number needs 3 digits. But I could not reproduce it in my grid, I just see that my numbers get clipped, which is not much better. I suggest you just set the width of your column to a fixed value:

```
{ text: 'No.', xtype: 'rownumberer', width: 50 }
```